# Is there an Arm Instructions parser for Ghidra that allows to replace References?

Tags: parsing, reference, arm, instructions, ghidra

I am trying to replace References in CodeUnits with Ghidra. The problem is that every instruction with a reference might look different e.g.:

```
bne LAB_00001234
```

or

```
cbz r3, LAB_00001234
```

My goal would be to just change the reference i.e. "LAB_00001234" and then assemble it again to get the corresponding bytes. Does Ghidra support this or do I have to parse everything on my own?